# How to reuse a dict-list cookie to send requests to websites using python?

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

I have a `dict-list` alike cookie that I want to reuse on the website.

How can I reuse it in `requests`?

Cookie:

```
[{'domain': '.123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1613158950,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': 'PHPSESS1D',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': '2518007f840d1ae0ee31b46ae078ddf9'},
 {'domain': '.123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1610759867,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': '_gid',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': 'GA1.2.1520267036.1610673468'},
 {'domain': '.123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1613158950,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': 'login_name',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': 'davidward0609%40gmail.com'},
 {'domain': '123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1613158950,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': 'PHPSESS1D',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': '2518007f840d1ae0ee31b46ae078ddf9'},
 {'domain': '.123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1610673527,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': '_gat_UA-35572274-1',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': '1'},
 {'domain': '123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1613158950,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': 'login_name',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': 'davidward0609%40gmail.com'},
 {'domain': '.123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1673745467,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': '_ga',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': 'GA1.2.1515925504.1610529178'},
 {'domain': '123doc.net',
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': 'PHPSESSID',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': 'tp111fpsbv93iks2euh02jucns'},
 {'domain': '.123doc.net',
  'expiry': 1644225179,
  'httpOnly': False,
  'name': '__gads',
  'path': '/',
  'secure': False,
  'value': 'ID=2a37ab8ee9659ced-227ee9ebabc50064:T=1610529179:RT=1610529179:S=ALNI_MYnwnEvryQuBFH1EE2AxDca4X2-RA'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your cookies seen like getting from selenium `driver.get_cookies()`.

Anyway, you can use this method to transform the cookie_list to cookie the `requests` can use.

```py
import requests
cookie = {}
for elem in cookie_list:
    cookie[elem["name"]] = elem["value"]

s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(cookie)
```

Comment: Hello !. How can I send thousands of requests after I have set cookies. I want to send thousands of requests to the website above. Code below. Thank you!

Comment: just use s.get or s.post, as s is now with the cookies